# Android Studio - issues resizing buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button

For some reason I can't manually resize any buttons on the design view using the handles. I can click and drag the handles but when I release, no changes are seen anywhere.

I'm using a relative layout.

Here is the xml for one of the buttons I'm trying to resize:

```
<Button
    android:text="√"
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#707070"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonLog"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonLog"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And the xml for the button's style and formatting (operator_style):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#00C7FC" />
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#9FEDFF" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#cccccc" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />
        <elevation
            android:elevation="2dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing layouts in android is not as easy as you think, because every android device has a different size. So everything is relative to each other. You can force the button to be a specific size in pixels, but when running your app on bigger screens this size will remain exactly the same pixel. You can achieve this by going to the properties of the button and fill in 100px instead of wrap_content or match_parent as width. I would not recommend this, try to make use of linear layouts and the other containers.

Use linear layouts and place all the buttons you want in this. Then set the weight of every button to set the size relative to each other. If you only want 1 button, just add a framelayout and you can try some things with the weight.

Comment: Is there any setting in Android Studio to update the values on the button properties when you drag it to resize it. When I drag to resize it just pops back (so  whats the point in the software allowing it)